# How to show only lines where a value is 'yes' in Excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have several data rows in one sheet and would like to only show the rows where a product is in stock -> 'yes'.

example:
I have 10 products/rows in the first sheet from line 1 to 10 and would like to only show the 5 products/rows which are in stock in the second sheet from line 1 to 5.

Can you point me to the best function for that? Would be great to do it without VBA (:

I was trying to get results with vlookup but I did not get it to work as needed.
I could use the IF-function but would get 5 empty rows I guess.

Comment: Sounds like you need `FILTER()` function if you are presently using `MS365` or `Excel 2021` or `Excel 2019`, if not the above then `INDEX()` with `AGGREGATE()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mayukh mentioned in comment, you can use `FILTER()` function in ***Sheet2*** `A1` cell like-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A11,Sheet1!B2:B11="yes")
```

[image]